# Ansible: Prompting variables for roles

Tags: ansible

I have a simple `ansible` Playbook called `setup.yml` which looks basically like this (simplified):

```
- hosts: my-server-to-setup
  remote_user: [REDACTED]
  become: yes
  #vars_prompt:
  #  - name: "zbxusername"
  #    prompt: "Zabbix Username"
  #    private: no    
  #  - name: "zbxpw"
  #     prompt: "Zabbix Passwort"
  #     private: yes
      roles:
       - basic
  #     - zabbix
```

The `zabbix` role requires a username and a password to acccess the zabbix host server. The credentials differ, every user has his own account.

If I want to install the `zabbix` role, I need to uncomment the `vars_prompt` section because `ansible` doesn't allow prompting from within a role.

Is there a better way to do this? The current way can possibly leave important variables undefined which would result in a playbook failure.

Answer (score 1):

Create a playbook *`top.yml`* that imports playbooks *`basic.yml`* and *`zabix.yml`*. Run the imported playbooks selectively with the tags.

```
ansible-playbook -t basic top.yml
ansible-playbook -t zabix top.yml
```

playbook top.yml

```
- name: Run basic
  import_playbook: basic.yml
  tags: [basic, never]

- name: Run zabix
  import_playbook: zabix.yml
  tags: [zabix, never]
```

playbook basic.yml

```
- hosts: my-server-to-setup
  remote_user: [REDACTED]
  become: yes
  roles:
    - basic
```

playbook zabix.yml

```
- hosts: my-server-to-setup
  remote_user: [REDACTED]
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "zbxusername"
      prompt: "Zabbix Username"
      private: no    
    - name: "zbxpw"
      prompt: "Zabbix Passwort"
      private: yes
  roles:
    - zabbix
```

---

Notes

The tag *`never`* might be useful not to accidentally run both roles. Without any tag specified none of the imported playbooks will run. There will be no action as a result of the following command.

```
ansible-playbook top.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I like this approach because I only need to comment out one part now (What you call "Run basic" etc).

Comment: You're welcome. I've added details. (Not sure what you need to comment).

Comment: Upon implementing I realized that the server is specified in both playbooks. Is it possible to specify this only in `top.yml`?